# VB.NET Calling webservice with Authentication key

Tags: vb.net, web-services, authentication, soap

I'm trying to setup a connection to a webservice from VB.NET I'm totally clueless on how to perform this. I receive an overview of what their Soap can do and i also received a securitykey. I'm however not sure how to call this webservice using the securitykey in VB.NET. Hope someone can help me a bit further using the layout of the service underneath.

This is the soap layout:

```
POST /Webservice/Coachview.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: training.coachview.net
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://coachview.net/webservices/ToevoegenWebAanvraag"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ToevoegenWebAanvraag xmlns="http://coachview.net/webservices">
      <aWebserviceAuthentication>
        <Key>string</Key>
      </aWebserviceAuthentication>
      <aWebAanvraag>
        <OpleidingsSoortCode>string</OpleidingsSoortCode>
        <OpleidingsSoortNaam>string</OpleidingsSoortNaam>
        <OpleidingCode>string</OpleidingCode>
        <OpleidingNaam>string</OpleidingNaam>
        <AantalPersonen>short</AantalPersonen>
        <ReferentieNrKlant>string</ReferentieNrKlant>
        <Uitvoeringstermijn>string</Uitvoeringstermijn>
        <Oorsprong>string</Oorsprong>
        <Opmerking>string</Opmerking>
        <ContactPersoonIsDeelnemer>boolean</ContactPersoonIsDeelnemer>
        <AanvraagIsOrder>boolean</AanvraagIsOrder>
      </aWebAanvraag>
      <aWebAanvraagBedrijf>
        <Naam>string</Naam>
        <Adres>string</Adres>
        <Postcode>string</Postcode>
        <Plaats>string</Plaats>
        <Land>string</Land>
        <BezoekAdres>string</BezoekAdres>
        <BezoekPostcode>string</BezoekPostcode>
        <BezoekPlaats>string</BezoekPlaats>
        <BezoekLand>string</BezoekLand>
        <FactuurAdres>string</FactuurAdres>
        <FactuurPostcode>string</FactuurPostcode>
        <FactuurPlaats>string</FactuurPlaats>
        <FactuurLand>string</FactuurLand>
        <Emailadres>string</Emailadres>
        <Telefoonnummer>string</Telefoonnummer>
        <Faxnummer>string</Faxnummer>
        <Opmerking>string</Opmerking>
        <Website>string</Website>
        <ExternId>string</ExternId>
        <ExternSource>string</ExternSource>
      </aWebAanvraagBedrijf>
      <aContactPersoon>
        <Achternaam>string</Achternaam>
        <Voorletters>string</Voorletters>
        <Tussenvoegsels>string</Tussenvoegsels>
        <Voornaam>string</Voornaam>
        <Titel>string</Titel>
        <Geslacht>string</Geslacht>
        <Adres>string</Adres>
        <Postcode>string</Postcode>
        <Plaats>string</Plaats>
        <Land>string</Land>
        <Afdeling>string</Afdeling>
        <Functie>string</Functie>
        <Faxnummer>string</Faxnummer>
        <GeboorteDatum>string</GeboorteDatum>
        <GeboortePlaats>string</GeboortePlaats>
        <TelefoonMobiel>string</TelefoonMobiel>
        <TelefoonDirect>string</TelefoonDirect>
        <Emailadres>string</Emailadres>
        <Opmerking>string</Opmerking>
        <ExternId>string</ExternId>
        <ExternSource>string</ExternSource>
      </aContactPersoon>
      <theDeelnemers>
        <WebAanvraagPersoon>
          <Achternaam>string</Achternaam>
          <Voorletters>string</Voorletters>
          <Tussenvoegsels>string</Tussenvoegsels>
          <Voornaam>string</Voornaam>
          <Titel>string</Titel>
          <Geslacht>string</Geslacht>
          <Adres>string</Adres>
          <Postcode>string</Postcode>
          <Plaats>string</Plaats>
          <Land>string</Land>
          <Afdeling>string</Afdeling>
          <Functie>string</Functie>
          <Faxnummer>string</Faxnummer>
          <GeboorteDatum>string</GeboorteDatum>
          <GeboortePlaats>string</GeboortePlaats>
          <TelefoonMobiel>string</TelefoonMobiel>
          <TelefoonDirect>string</TelefoonDirect>
          <Emailadres>string</Emailadres>
          <Opmerking>string</Opmerking>
          <ExternId>string</ExternId>
          <ExternSource>string</ExternSource>
        </WebAanvraagPersoon>
        <WebAanvraagPersoon>
          <Achternaam>string</Achternaam>
          <Voorletters>string</Voorletters>
          <Tussenvoegsels>string</Tussenvoegsels>
          <Voornaam>string</Voornaam>
          <Titel>string</Titel>
          <Geslacht>string</Geslacht>
          <Adres>string</Adres>
          <Postcode>string</Postcode>
          <Plaats>string</Plaats>
          <Land>string</Land>
          <Afdeling>string</Afdeling>
          <Functie>string</Functie>
          <Faxnummer>string</Faxnummer>
          <GeboorteDatum>string</GeboorteDatum>
          <GeboortePlaats>string</GeboortePlaats>
          <TelefoonMobiel>string</TelefoonMobiel>
          <TelefoonDirect>string</TelefoonDirect>
          <Emailadres>string</Emailadres>
          <Opmerking>string</Opmerking>
          <ExternId>string</ExternId>
          <ExternSource>string</ExternSource>
        </WebAanvraagPersoon>
      </theDeelnemers>
    </ToevoegenWebAanvraag>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ToevoegenWebAanvraagResponse xmlns="http://coachview.net/webservices">
      <ToevoegenWebAanvraagResult>string</ToevoegenWebAanvraagResult>
    </ToevoegenWebAanvraagResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a webreference to the location where the .asmx is running.
Use the webreference on the location where you want to do something with it.

In my case my code looked something like this:

```
//On top of my class
Imports net.coachview.training

//On the location where i needed it
Dim aWebserviceAuthentication As New WebserviceAuthentication
        aWebserviceAuthentication.Key = "xxx"
Dim aCoachviewnetWebservices As New CoachviewnetWebservices()

            inschrijvingNummer = aCoachviewnetWebservices.ToevoegenWebAanvraag(aWebserviceAuthentication, aWebAanvraag, aanvraagBedrijf, contactPersoon, colDeelnemers)
```

Where all types are just used from the webservice reference.